# JAXB - Duplicate elements starting with lower case letter

Tags: jaxb, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

The following test that I provide runs under WildFly 13 (JEE 7 / JAXB v2.2) correctly.
Under WildFly 19 (JEE8 / JAXB v2.3) fails with the erroneous output that I attach.

```
@Test
public void test_marshaller() throws JAXBException {
    SPC spc = new SPC();
    spc.setAdminInfo(new AdminInfo());
    spc.getAdminInfo().setAuthorisation(new Authorisation());
    spc.setLang(LanguageCode.valueOf("en"));
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SPC.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    System.out.println("Marshaller package is " + Marshaller.class.getPackage());
    System.out.println("Marshaller generic string is " + marshaller.getClass().toGenericString());
    System.out.println("Marshaller class Name is " + marshaller.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("Context Name is " + context.getClass().getName());

    marshaller.marshal(spc, System.out);
}
```

Under WF 13 I receive the following correct output:

```
<ns4:SPC xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ns4="http://echa.europa.eu/schema/spc/1.0/" xml:lang="en">
    <ns4:AdminInfo>
        <ns4:Authorisation>
            <ns4:Date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns4:Expiry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns4:Authorisation>
    </ns4:AdminInfo>
    <ns4:AuthorisedUses/>
</ns4:SPC>
```

and under WF 19 I receive the following erroneous output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:SPC xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ns4="http://echa.europa.eu/schema/spc/1.0/" xml:lang="en">
    <ns4:adminInfo>
        <ns4:Authorisation>
            <ns4:Date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns4:Expiry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns4:Authorisation>
    </ns4:adminInfo>
    <ns4:lang>
        <representation>en</representation>
    </ns4:lang>
    <ns4:AdminInfo>
        <ns4:Authorisation>
            <ns4:Date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns4:Expiry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns4:Authorisation>
    </ns4:AdminInfo>
    <ns4:AuthorisedUses/>
</ns4:SPC>
```

Please note the `adminInfo` & `AdminInfo`.

I would like to have only one node starting with capital letter.

Any ideas what could raise the duplicate elements?

**--- UPDATE ---**

I generate the SPC through an XSD with the help of this maven plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
...
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.9.0</version>
                        </plugin>                       
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
```

Comment: What does your class `SPC` look like? Did you generate it from an XSD or write it manually?

Comment: Could this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511321/i-need-to-marshal-to-xml-i-am-getting-duplicate-values-in-my-xml-file

Comment: All the `@XmlElement` are generated as duplicates (even if they have the same first letter capitalization) and all the `@XmlAttribute` are generated as attributes and elements with the same value.
The XML accesor type of the SPC class is `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)`